# How to add web capabilities to react native app

Tags: react-native

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjf0l.png)
I have a React Native App that works but I want to be able to build for the web. Any help would be deeply appreciated.
Below is my package.json.

{
"name": "dotmac",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
},
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
"@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.7",
"@js-joda/core": "^5.2.0",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.3",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.1",
"@types/react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
"axios": "^0.26.1",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
"currency.js": "^2.0.4",
"flutterwave-react-native": "^1.0.2",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-hook-form": "^7.29.0",
"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
"react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
"react-native-onesignal": "^4.4.0",
"react-native-paystack-webview": "^4.0.3",
"react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.4",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
"react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
"react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
"react-native-webview": "^11.18.1",
"react-native-zohodesk-portal-sdk": "^1.0.6",
"react-native-zohosalesiq-mobilisten": "^4.2.10",
"twrnc": "^3.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
"@types/react-native": "^0.67.3",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.17.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.17.0",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
"typescript": "^4.4.4"
},
"resolutions": {
"@types/react": "^17"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native",
"moduleFileExtensions": [
"ts",
"tsx",
"js",
"jsx",
"json",
"node"
]
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Integrating react-native-web to an existing project is kinda difficult process. You can follow the official documentation here (https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/installation/)